# Working on my own Javascript countdown timer/ Pomodoro technique

Tags: javascript

Since I have been teaching myself how to code in JavaScript by watching tutorials on YouTube and reading Head First Javascript book, I decided to set my own challenge by building something that has been quite effective to me - The Pomodoro technique! I have been using this technique since I have started learning JavaScript. And whilst I was thinking of a JavaScript coding challenge that involves arrays, functions, DOM, etc. I thought why not the Pomodoro technique that can have an array of activities to do during my 5-minute break, a function for the 25 and 5-minute timer and then style it using HTML and CSS. Anyway, here is my code so far...

```
    <script>

        function startTimer() {
            var timer = document.getElementById("myTimer").innerHTML;
            var arr = timer.split(":");
            var hour = arr[0];
            var min = arr[1];
            var sec = arr[2];
            if (sec == 0) {
                if (min == 0) {
                    if (hour == 0) {
                        alert(pushup());
                        window.location.reload();
                        return;
                    }
                    hour--;
                    min = 60;
                    if (hour < 10) hour = "0" + hour;
                }
                min--;
                if (min < 10) min = "0" + min;
                sec = 59;
            }
            else sec--;

            if (sec < 10) sec = "0" + sec;

            document.getElementById("myTimer").innerHTML = hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
            setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);


        function pushup() {
            var minBreak = ["Do 5 push ups!", "Do 10 push ups!", "Do 15 push ups!",
                         "Do 5 sit ups!", "Do 10 sit ups!", "Do 15 sit ups!",
                         "Clean room!", "Do laundry!", "Walk dog!" ];

            var rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * minBreak.length);

            var phrase = minBreak[rand1];
            alert(phrase)
        };
        };


    </script>
</head>

<body onload="startTimer();">
        <p id="myTimer">00:00:10</p>
</body>
```

I did this step by step creating the pushup function first, which was easy to do, setting alerts on each step so I knew I was going on the right track too. However, startTime function is a copy on a YouTube video. As much as I would have loved to figure this out myself I was struggling hard to set a timer in the browser! The only successful way I can do was use the setInterval method. However, the video was only one minute long and it does not explain how it works. I made sure I gone through line to line to understand how it works, the .split method, why multiple of if statements, etc. Wrote notes down and make sure I understood. Now, when the timer goes off at 10 secs it alerts one of the minBreak chores in random, success!  BUT then shows another alert saying "The page says undefined" why is this? And (because I am new to creating this) how would you have written this code? I am thinking to have multiple variables of different chores. So, var pushup will have an array of 1 push up, 2 push up and so on. var situp will have an array of 1 situp, 2 situp and so on. What statements or methods should I use so the math.random can pick one of many different variables arrays randomly instead of being all in one. Not really asking for you to show me a code of how it's done but a route of using for statements, or while, or ifs, etc. sorry if doesn't make sense.. I am new to this! But just trying to make something up on the way and challenge myself, and question myself. but at the same time need a mentor/ teacher to show me the way.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `undefined` message, because you have twice an `alert`. The second one uses a function return value to display, but that function does not return anything, hence `undefined`:

```
alert(pushup());
```

So the function `pushup` performs itself an `alert`, which is like you want it. But then the function returns to the above statement, where the function's result is displayed in an `alert`. It is `undefined`.

So you can fix this by just calling the function:

```
pushup();
```

As far as I understand this was the only issue to be fixed.